# Controller Check if Agent Name is already created

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to add logic to check if the agent name is already created and alert the user. I created this IQueryable SearchAgents which takes in a string query and I was going to add it to the controller but I am not sure if this is the correct way.

> Is this the correct path for validating an agent is already in the system?

AgentController

```
    [HttpPost]
            [ApplicationApiAuthorize("Administrator, ContentManager")]
            public IHttpActionResult CreateAgent([FromBody]AgentModel agentModel)
            {
                LogHelper.Info($"Creating agent {agentModel.Name}");
//Search if Agent name is in the system
            var AgentId = AgentsDataService.SearchAgents.Select(a => new AgentModel {Name = agentModel.Name }).ToList();

                var agentEntity = new Agent();
                Mapper.DynamicMap(agentModel, agentEntity);

                var agentInformationEntities = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<AgentInformation>>(agentModel.AgentInformations);
                agentEntity.AgentInformations = new EntitySet<AgentInformation>();
                agentEntity.AgentInformations.AddRange(agentInformationEntities);

                var operationResult = AgentsDataService.InsertAgent(agentEntity);                        

                var result = Ok(new
                {
                    Value = Mapper.Map<AgentModel>(operationResult)
                });

                return result;
            }
```

AgentDataService

```
public IQueryable<Agent> SearchAgents(string query)
    {
        return GetAllAgents().Where(a => a.Name.Contains(query)).OrderBy(a => a.Name);
    }
```

Comment: You're missing parameter passing to `SearchAgents`. Update line as `var AgentId = AgentsDataService.SearchAgents(agentModel.Name).Select(a => new AgentModel {Name = agentModel.Name }).ToList();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally since you only want to know if the entity exists in the database or not I would have the following method in the `AgentDataService`

```
public bool AgentExists(string agentName)
{
    return GetAllAgents().Any(x => x.Name.Equals(agentName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

or the async version (Assuming you are using Entity Framework):

```
public async Task<bool> AgentExistsAsync(string agentName)
{
    return await GetAllAgents().AnyAsync(x => x.Name.Equals(agentName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

Then you can call this from your controller and inform the user if the agent exists.

Comment: Then in IAgentsDataService I would created an interface bool AgentExists(string agentName);

Comment: Yes add it to the interface

Comment: any idea why I would be getting this error {"Method 'Boolean Equals(System.String, System.StringComparison)' has no supported translation to SQL."}

Comment: Just change the query to `x.Name == agentName` in the AgentExists Method